# Trying to send a file pathname to a constructor

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to send the pathname that is acquired from my openButton to the constructor so that I can then use the information within it. Can anyone see how  could do this?

```
namespace GPSCalculator
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
       private String[] items;
       int count = 0;
       string FileName;
       public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            List<float> inputList = new List<float>();
            TextReader tr = new StreamReader(FileName);
            String input = Convert.ToString(tr.ReadToEnd());
            items = input.Split(',');

        }
private void openToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
            ofd.Filter = "Csv Files (*.csv)|*.csv|Text files (*.txt)|*.txt|All files (*.*)|*.*";
            if (ofd.ShowDialog(this).Equals(DialogResult.OK))
            {
                var FileName = (ofd.FileName);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `public Form1(string fname) { FileName=fname;.......`

Comment: The openToolStripMenuItem_Click is an event inside the Form1 class?

Comment: One problem here is the line `var FileName = (ofd.FileName);`  This line declares a local variable that hides the field.  Also, don't create the StreamReader in the constructor; you have to create it once you know what the file name is, so, therefore, in the body of the openToolStripMenuItem_Click method.

Comment: @L.B it seems that the purpose of the form is to allow the user to select and open a file.  If that's true, your suggestion won't help.

Comment: Thankyou phoog you make a good point :)

Comment: @phoog I wrote it according to title....

Comment: @L.B aha, I had lost sight of the title (literally, through scrolling).

Answer (score 0):

```
       //add filename to the constructor
       public Form1(string filename)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            List<float> inputList = new List<float>();
            //use the filename from the constructor to open the StreamReader
            TextReader tr = new StreamReader(filename);
            //set your FileName filename passed in
            FileName = filename;
            String input = Convert.ToString(tr.ReadToEnd());
            items = input.Split(',');

        }
```

Comment: Thankyou for your response Daniel, but phoog made a goood point which I am going to use

Answer (score 0):

You can't, the button on the form can't call it's own constructor so you need to move some of the operations in the constructor into a separate method.

```
namespace GPSCalculator
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private string[] items;
        private int count = 0;
        private string fileName;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void openToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
            ofd.Filter = "Csv Files (*.csv)|*.csv|Text files (*.txt)|*.txt|All files (*.*)|*.*";
            if (ofd.ShowDialog(this).Equals(DialogResult.OK))
            {
                // I've changed this to refer to the field and removed un-necessary parenthesis
                this.fileName = ofd.FileName;
            }
        }

        private void ReadFileContents()
        {
            List<float> inputList = new List<float>(); // This doesn't get used?!

            // StreamReader is IDisposable so it should be used in a using statement
            using(TextReader tr = new StreamReader(this.fileName))
            {
                string input = Convert.ToString(tr.ReadToEnd());
                this.items = input.Split(',');
            }
        }
    }
}
```